# How to get changed post title in my custom plug-in which fires when 'save_post' is called?

Tags: plugin-development, filters, save-post, get-the-title

I created a custom WordPress plug-in that hooks onto 'save_post" using add_filter(). I need to do something with the post titles and whenever a user changes the title, my plug-in cannot get the new title until the post is updated a second time (without changing the title in the admin a second time).

For example, I have a post named "WordPress Rocks". I change it to "WordPress is Cool", but my plug-in shows the title as being "WordPress Rocks" using get_the_title($post_id) when updating the post. I go back and make a second update to the post, this time without changing the title. This next time, get_the_title($post_id) shows the title is "WordPress is Cool".

How can I grab the updated title (if it's changed) as soon as the post is updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument of the `save_post` action contains the post data:

```
do_action('save_post', $post_ID, $post);
```

You can also hook `post_updated` which will let you easily compare the before/after data:

```
do_action( 'post_updated', $post_ID, $post_after, $post_before);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm confused about where to run do_action(). Here is how I'm calling save_post: public function __construct() { add_filter("save_post", array($this, "runCode")); }

Comment: sorry, these bits are from [core source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/post.php#L2690) where the actions you're hooking are actually called. see the `$accepted_args` argument of [`add_action`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) to access the additional passed data. also note `save_post` is an action, not a filter!